# what doesn ORC stand for in llvm

Tags: llvm

For example in LLVM's doc:

https://llvm.org/docs/ORCv2.html

It mentions ORC JIT many times but doesn't explain ORC.

Comment: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT1.html "This tutorial runs through the implementation of a JIT compiler using LLVM’s On-Request-Compilation (ORC) APIs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT1.html "This tutorial runs through the implementation of a JIT compiler using LLVM’s On-Request-Compilation (ORC) APIs."

by Joe